# Facebook publish_actions submission review answer

Tags: android, facebook

So I submitted my app for review. And the answer I got was this:

> Your app is using Share plugin to share content so you don't need to submit for review. Publish_actions is only for posting through Graph API

But I use the Graph API to get scores of people who log in with Facebook and to populate a leaderboard. If anyone knows what I am doing wrong feel free to tell me. Thanks

Comment: To get scores you don't need publish_actions. If you need it you need to explain to the reviewer why you need it

Comment: Look even their project says that for scores you need publish_actions and that you have to submit for review  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/scores-achievements

Comment: To publish scores yes.

Comment: So how can i specify that i need it because i send them the APK file and a video of me playing the game. So they can't have missed the leaderbord. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Write a more detailed explanation …?

Comment: Okay thank you :D .